# Trouble with python nodes in launchfile

Tags: python, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone!

I am trying to start some additional nodes together with the minimal.launch file, so I made the following additions for my nodes.

I sourced the devel/setup.bash file so the package can be found and made sure the py files are executable using chmod +x.  Nonetheless, when I try to run the launch file, I get the following errors. It does seem quite generic to me, has someone experienced this before and has an idea?

Thank you!

The lines I added:

```
  <node name="webcam_pub" pkg="webcam_pub" type="webcam_pub.py" />
  <node name="pos_pub" pkg="stop_snap" type="pos_pub.py" />
  <node name="go_to_goal_v5" pkg="stop_snap" type="go_to_goal_v5.py" />
```

What I get as output in the console (log files are empty).

```
process[webcam_pub-14]: started with pid [6036]
: No such file or directory
failed to start local process: /home/turtlebot/library_ws/src/stop_snap/src/pos$
local launch of stop_snap/pos_pub.py failed
[pos_pub-15] process has died [pid -1, exit code 127, cmd /home/turtlebot/libra$
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/69123a30-181f-11e6-bce9-54353050d249/pos_pub$
process[go_to_goal_v5-16]: started with pid [6061]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234202/trouble-with-python-nodes-in-launchfile/) by [ebaumert](https://answers.ros.org/users/25969/ebaumert/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2016-05-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I sourced the devel/setup.bash file so the package can be found and made sure the py files are executable using chmod +x. Nonetheless, when I try to run the launch file, I get the following errors.

Do you have the required [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) for Python at the top of your file? If not, `roslaunch` cannot start it, as it tries to start your scripts directly (ie: it doesn't prefix it with `python /path/to/your/script.py`).

If you have it, make sure your files have the proper Unix line-endings. If you have edited thins under Windows (fi because you have ROS in a VM), they can be changed / mixed, which will lead to all sorts of strange errors (they're not actually 'strange', but the symptoms can be confusing).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2